# COLDFUSION: Component [Document] has no accessible Member with name [FILENAME]

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

i am trying to save a document (image in article). i use article uid as document filename. what i want to save in document is:

-caption (string text consists of the description of the image).

-fileName (string text consists of the article uid)

-fileHref (path to image location).

here is my code:

Document Handler:

```
function save (event, rc, prc) localmode="modern" {

    prc.article = articleService.findWhere({"uid"=rc.fileName});
    
    try {
        if (prc.article.hasDocument()) {
            response = {
                "status" = "error",
                "message" = "Article already have an image.",
                "data" = {}
            };
        } else {
            structUpdate(rc,"fileName", #rc.fileName#&".jpg");
            prc.document = documentService.new(rc);
            documentService.save(prc.document);
            
            prc.article.addDocument(prc.document);
            articleService.save(prc.article);

            response = {
                "status" = "success",
                "message" = "",
                "data" = prc.document// Include newly uploaded image info. in struct
            };
        }
    } catch(e) {
        response = {
            "status" = "error",
            "message" = e.message,
            "data" = {}
        };
        log.fatal("Failed to create image file.", e.message);
    }

    event.renderData(type="json", data=response);
}
```

Document bean:

```
component entityname="Document" persistent="true" extends="BaseEntity" {

    // primary key
    
    // secondary key
    property name="uid" ormtype="string" unique="true";

    // non-relational columns
    property name="fileName" ormtype="string" unique="true";
    property name="caption"  ormtype="string";

    // one-to-one

    // one-to-many

    // many-to-one
    property name="article" fieldtype="many-to-one" cfc="Article" fkcolumn="articleId" fetch="join";

    // many-to-many

    // calculated properties
    property name="fileHref" ormtype="string" persistent="false";

    // non-persistent

    // object constraints
    this.constraints = {
        "caption" = { required=true, requiredMessage="Please enter Document caption." },
        "fileName" = { required=true, requiredMessage="Please enter Document file." }
    };

    // methods
    function init() localmode="modern" {
        if(isNull(variables.uid)){
            variables.uid = lCase(right(createUUID(), 16));
        }
        return this;
    }

    function onDIComplete() localmode="modern" {
        variables.fileHref = "/docs/article/" & variables.fileName;
    }

}
```

as you can see i already have set the fileName in my bean. but system can access that fileName property.
sorry i am not fluent in english.

Comment: what is the error you are seeing and what line is being reported?

Comment: The error that i see:
Type:  expression
Message:  Component [Document] has no accessible Member with name [FILENAME]
Detail:  enable [trigger data member] in administrator to also invoke getters and setters
Timestamp:  07/16/2020 08:12:30 AM

Comment: Line 62 in DocumentService

61:   articleService = wirebox.getInstance("ArticleService");
62:   article = articleService.findWhere({"uid"=params.fileName});

Line 59 in Document handler
57:     structUpdate(rc,"fileName", #rc.fileName#&".jpg");
58:     prc.document = documentService.new(rc);
59:     documentService.save(prc.document);

Comment: sounds like maybe the code is expecting get/set for cfc properties/members but the setting is not enable for the server...? Not sure otherwise. Good luck

Comment: @DanRoberts sorry for the late reply. its my fault to call the wrong bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i called the wrong bean in the handler so this is happen.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can elaborate what is the correct bin, and add code snippets how was that solved.